# Parsing java map returned as JSON response using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I didn't found any specific answer which addresses the below question.

I have the following JSON response fetched through an AJAX POST request.

```
{
"result":
{
"101010":["PRAVAT","SGSGSG","UKEMP5","UKENTD","WAUK01","MK87UK"],
"202020":["CORA1E","PSASAS","EDCRJS","USHC01","USDR06"],
............................
........................
"304050":["ERCDE2","DELT01","DECGKG","DEHC03","IS02","DEPI01"]
},
"status":"SUCCESS"
}
```

I want to display the data above data by using a loop in javascript.
I tried `for ( var i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {` but I am not able to do so.

Please help how can I parse and display my data in the above JSON format using javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is an object, not an array. Only arrays have the length property. To iterate over an object use:

```
$.post("yoururlhere", function(JSONData) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(JSONData);
    if (obj.status.toLowerCase() === "success") {
        for (var key in obj.result) {
            if (obj.result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               console.log(key + ': ' + obj.result[key]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The if (obj.result.hasOwnProperty(key)) forces the for to ignore prototype properties. If you care to look it up they are the means you can do inheritance in Javascript.

Comment: Hi Hoffmann, when I am using $.parseJSON(json), i am gettin the following error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: @PravatPanda oh It was missing a closing parentheses on the last line before. I fixed it

Comment: @PravatPanda the if was wrong, it is if (obj.result.hasOwnProperty(key)) it was missing the ".result" part. I already fixed it.

Comment: Instead of manually parsing it in the callback, just pass "json" as the 4th parameter to `$.post()`, letting jQuery handle it

Answer (score 4):

Do you have it as an object or JSON?

To convert the JSON to an object in jquery, use `$.parseJSON()`.

EG. `var obj = $.parseJSON(myJSONData);`

Once you have the object, you can loop through the keys using:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: when I am using $.parseJSON(json), i am gettin the following error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Answer (score 1):

You should parse it, You can use `JSON.parse()` or `jQuery.parseJSON()`.
Have a look at this: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Luckily, jQuery determines the best choice of parsing the string. If `JSON.parse` is available, it uses that. If it's not, it uses it's own way. So if you have jQuery included, it's safe enough to just call `jQuery.parseJSON()` and the best path should be taken. At the same time, `JSON.parse()` (and a polyfill for it) more "safely" parses the string, so some might think it's better not to allow jQuery to use its own method

Answer (score 0):

As MostafaR said, you need to parse it into a javascript object first. When you get JSON from somewhere, javascript just considers it a string, so you won't be able to access it directly. Also, some older browsers don't have window.JSON, so you'll need to include [the json2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you're worried about support from older browsers.